# How do North American people pronounce "wants us to ..." in a linked way?

Tags: spoken-english

> Paul wants us to go over ...

I heard [it](https://soundcloud.com/xi-zhang-819295156/wants-us-to-go-over) to

> Paul wants to screw over ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't hear the "screw", I guess because I know what she *is* saying.

For some reason she emphasizes "Paul". But the way she almost eliminates the sound of the "us" and the "to" is pretty typical for words that aren't important in the sentence. If either of those words were very significant to her meaning (for instance if asking "*us*" to go over is a new development, and a change from the original plan, maybe), then she would probably say it a little more clearly. But as it is, it sounds like the most important point in her statement is that *Paul* is the one who wants them to come. The "us" and the "to" are obvious and unimportant, so she just barely hints at their consonants quickly as almost "attachments" to the surrounding words.

To me it sounds like:

"... **PAUL** wants's t'gəw**over** on Friday...

The other syllables are pretty clear and distinct, but  "us" & "to" become **'s** and **t'**  , respectively.